# Параметры для UnityTest

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу юнит-тест, и хотелось бы поместить простой параметр в аргументы тестового метода, а затем атрибутами задать варианты, но не могу понять, как это сделать. Вроде всё делаю по [примеру](https://medium.com/xrpractices/all-you-need-to-know-about-testing-in-unity3d-part-1-70658818ce5e) (скрин, чтобы не переходить по ссылке и не искать нужное место), но не могу разобраться с атрибутом

> [image]

```
[UnityTest]
[UnityEngine.Range(-1, 1)]
public void Test(float parameter)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(something);
}
```

[image: Реальность]

**UPD:**
Пробовал ещё такой вариант, но тоже не работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы делаете совершенно не как в примере - вам написано в одном месте, а вы вписываете в совершенно другое.

Comment: @AK , Спасибо, Вы правы. Можете вынести свой коммент как ответ?

Comment: Зачем? Логичнее закрыть как "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. "